# How to create a index to search firstname or last name (Active Admin in rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, activeadmin

I have search functionality in active admin of rails which has filter option:

```
  filter :profile_display_name_or_profile_firstname_or_profile_lastname_or_email,
         as: :string,
         label: "Search Name/Email"
```

which generates below query

```
"SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM accounts LEFT OUTER JOIN profiles ON profiles . account_id = 
accounts . id WHERE ( ( ( profiles . display_name LIKE ? OR profiles . firstname LIKE ? )
 OR profiles . lastname LIKE ? ) OR accounts . email LIKE ? )"
```

and this is making slower performance in production. I want to speed the performance time.

so I am trying to separate the filters

```
  filter :profile_display_name_or_profile_firstname_or_profile_lastname,
         as: :string,
         filters: [:starts_with, :equals, :contains, :ends_with],
         label: "Search Name"
  filter :email,
         as: :string,
         filters: [:starts_with, :equals, :contains, :ends_with],
         label: "Search Email"
```

Also, I want to create the index on first_name, last_name , display_name

```
add_index :profiles, %i[firstname lastname displayname],
              name: "index_profiles_on_firstname_and_lastname_and_displayname"
```

My question is I am searching with either first name or lastname or displayname do I need to index all once or separately.

what should be good solution to optimise the above query.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this index

```
FULLTEXT(display_name, firstname, lastname, lastname, email)
```

Then do

```
WHERE MATCH(display_name, firstname, lastname, lastname, email)
      AGAINST('?' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks but the query is inbuilt generated functionality from active admin gem for filter option [link] (https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html) so I cannot change the query.

Comment: Condolences.  There are a hundred products out that each allow 90% of the database functionality.  This is a case where you need part of the 10%.